# Http Header - Cache-Control: max-age - behaviour?

Tags: http, iis, http-headers, httprequest, fiddler

*I've been reading a lot about this  , but still there are few misunderstandings.*

I read that the `max-age`  should be set only to static data.

I used fiddler composer to make this request

```
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: www.example.com
```

the response is :

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 01 Jan 2013 20:37:31 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS)
Last-Modified: Thu, 06 Dec 2012 19:40:14 GMT <======
...
```

Q#1

If the server sends the `last-modified` header , is it becuase that the page is a static one ? ( someone has set `max-age`) at the server side ?

Q#2

After a client got this first  response , the next time it will  ask it is with `If-Modified-Since` header and the server might return `200` or `304` (not Modified).
**But why**  the server in his *first response* didn't already mention the `max-age` ? it could save the client from sending the second request !

Q#3

Alghough this conditional get suppose to save me from downloading the whole page , is [**is still discourage**](http://books.google.co.il/books?id=fCK3MMV8iYcC&pg=PA64&lpg=PA64&dq=%22Even%20though%20the%20responses%20to%20conditional%20GETs%20are%20short,%20the%20time%20it%20takes%20for%20the%20round-trips%20alone%22&source=bl&ots=F5E11mEezn&sig=jUvP2C88XzPvWSgwFDcKLZPsAEE&hl=en&sa=X&ei=qUzjUIC9Nsfj4QSsvIAw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22Even%20though%20the%20responses%20to%20conditional%20GETs%20are%20short,%20the%20time%20it%20takes%20for%20the%20round-trips%20alone%22&f=false)  , so what other option do I have ? ( for static data)

Q#4

How does the `iis` knows if it was modified or not ? by looking at the file date modified ? are you going to tell me that for every date check it is doing `IO` access ? if not  , where does it saves that info ?

Q#5

After the client got the first response it needs the page one more time. does it sending again a request with `If-Modified-Since` ? [if no](http://books.google.co.il/books?id=fCK3MMV8iYcC&pg=PA64&lpg=PA64&dq=%22the%20content%20will%20remain%20active%20in%20the%20cache,%20and%20the%20browser%20won%E2%80%99t%20make%20those%20extra%20server%22&source=bl&ots=F5E11mFatg&sig=AfZt60tXNE82GCKPlQRTHLPgI-M&hl=en&sa=X&ei=v07jUO7RIMrWsgblk4DQAQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22the%20content%20will%20remain%20active%20in%20the%20cache,%20and%20the%20browser%20won%E2%80%99t%20make%20those%20extra%20server%22&f=false) , what if the page *did* changed while this intreval ? and if yes  - why did the server responded with `max-age` header ? I have nothing to do with it.

Comment: You may want to have a look at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/07/14/caching-improvements-in-internet-explorer-9.aspx, which helps explain the relationships between these headers. Also, look at Fiddler's *Caching* response Inspector.

Comment: @EricLaw Isn't by default the `last-modified-header` should be there ? I just created a page and it is not there. how can I make the last-modified header to be there ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The max-age clause of the Cache-Control header has to be enabled explicitly.  The exact manner of doing so, obviously, depends on the [server software](http://www.webscalingblog.com/performance/caching-http-headers-cache-control-max-age.html).

The Last-Modified: and If-Modified-Since: interaction is independent of this, because that mechanism was invented long before max-age.

You will always get a Last-Modified: for any server side resource that the server does not know (again, by server-specific means) to be dynamically generated. Cache-Control: max-age=whatever, if also present, allows the client or cache to save on update requests (using If-Modified-Since).

But this extra header requires a server setting. It does not happen automatically for "static data".  Nor does a Last-Modified: indicate "static data". (It is possible for a server side handler process to generate a Last-Modified header to be relayed to the client.)

Q1: No.  The server was not configured to recognize the data as dynamic.  max-age has nothing to do with it.

Q2:  Because max-age was not enabled.  It does not happen automatically.

Q3: No other option.  If-Modified-Since was designed to save on bandwidth.

Q4: IIS, like all other servers, has to be [configured to enable max-age](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/staticcontent/clientcache).  No guesswork involved.  As for determining whether something has changed, this *does* involve a comparison of the date sent by the client in the If-Modified-Since header with date information stored on the server.  For static data in a file this would typically involve a system call such as GetFileAttributesEx() on Windows, or fstat() on other platforms.

Q5: If a client issues an update request (with If-Modified-Since:) before a Cache-Control: max-age previously received from the server has expired, then either the client is broken, or it is executing an externally triggered "force update/refresh" option.  (Note that an If-Modified-Since request pressupposes that the client still has the previous version, in some cache.  If it doesn't, then it will not send this header, simply because it doesn't have the date!)

Comment: Can you explain more q#2 ?

Comment: The server sends a max-age header only if this is _enabled_ for the URL in question.  This enabling does _not_ happen automatically.  You seem to be under the impression that this does happen automatically for static data.  But, it does _not_. The admin has to enable it, on a file by file basis.

Comment: Can you please go to chat ? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22048/room-for-royi-namir-and-arayq2

Comment: Sorry, I'm in an environment that doesn't allow access.

Comment: Another possible source of confusion: you may be under the impression that max-age must have been already set in order for a Last-Modified header to be sent. This is _not_ true either. max-age and Last-Modified have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: I know that in order to use max-age I must definie it in a server (in my iis) like : http://www.code-magazine.com/ArticleImage.aspx?QuickID=100013&Image=figure3-2.jpg . but should I use it only for static files like js / images etc ? ( no html) ?

Comment: You can use it for any file you like, just be aware of the consequences: that caches, especially ones in between your server and any client, will not check with your server for updates until the age setting expires.

Comment: he _will_ check for updates using `If-Modified-Since` no ???? I'm totally confused now. ( and i read so many articles). thats why the `If-Modified-Since` is exists for !!

Comment: The purpose of a Cache-Control: max-age header is to inform the requester that If-Modified-Since requests are not necessary until the age expires. If clients do it anyway, then either they are broken, or they are not programmed to recognize the max-age header, or someone has forced a "refresh".

Comment: Whatever browser specific method applies.  And it isn't restricted to browsers.

Comment: so if i enabled max-age in the server-  the first time a user will request this resource- it will be send back to the client with max-age header and will not make any further requests to the server.only when the max-age expires- **then** the client will add `if-modified since` header...right ?

Comment: so when I will get a response from the server with `Last-Modified` header?  I created a simple request like `GET http://www.iana.org/domains/example/ HTTP/1.1  
User-Agent: Fiddler  
Host: www.iana.org` and did get the `Last-Modified` header back... so when will i see it ? always ?

Comment: Pretty much always. You may even get it for dynamically generated data, with Last-Modified set to a few seconds ago (or even in the future, if the clock on your machine is behind the server's)!

Comment: so max-age and if-modified-since is not related !. if i get max-age i shut up and keep waiting. but if i get last-modified - then I ask the server if there is a new version. right ?

Comment: Is max-age relative to the date of request or the last modifed header?